# Catch exception after retries inside saga

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, masstransit, saga

I'm working on a POC using Kafka and Masstransit and I just stumble upon a weird scenario. I'm using a very simple retry police which basically retries at any exception during the execution flow. It works fine, that is, it retries at everything and throws an `EventExecutionException` exception. The problem is that I can't catch this (or any) exception this **goes through a retry** inside a `.catch<>` method.

When I define a Saga block like the bellow one it catches the exception right away, so don't retry it. I wonder if there's a way to "wait" the retries and then catch the exception and work on some sort of compensation inside the saga `.catch<>` block.

Part of my saga:

```
Initially(
    When(OrderRequestedEvent)
        .InitializeSaga()
        .Then(context => LogContext.Info?.Log("Order requested: {0}", context.Saga.CorrelationId))
        .Activity(config => config.OfType<ReceiveOrderRequestStepActivity>())
        .TransitionTo(ValidatingCustomer)
        .Catch<EventExecutionException>(p => p.TransitionTo(Faulted)
            .Activity(x => x.OfType<ReceiveOrderRequestStepActivity>())));
```

In this scenario, I'm trying to handle the thrown exception inside the `Faulted` method of an `IStateMachineActivity`.

This is my very simple retry policy configuration:

```
rider.AddSagaStateMachine<OrderRequestStateMachine, OrderRequestSagaInstance>(c =>
{
    c.UseMessageRetry(r =>
    {
        r.Interval(kafkaTopics.MaxRetriesAttempts, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
    });
}).InMemoryRepository();
```